# Javascript Object showing null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate am empty object with data being returned from a POST request. The data is being returned successfully, but in the code the object is found to be null. The code is given below:

```
var item = {};   
var args= {p: "<?php echo $id; ?>"};

$.post('api.php', args, function(response) {

    startSpinner(spinner);
    if (response.status == 0) {
        item = response.data;
        console.log("ITEM: " + JSON.stringify(item));
    }

}).done(function() {
    ..
});

if (item == null || item == undefined) {
    alert("TTEMST");
}
```

In the console log, the item is clearly being shown to get populated with data, but the if condition for a null object is somehow being satisfied, i.e. the alert box is being displayed. I think there is something wrong with the way I am populating the object. Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.post()` is asynchronous. `alert` execute before your success callback

Comment: Thank you so much, I am still getting used to asynchronous execution!

Answer (score 1):

This line of code will most likely run before the post returns. You should add that to the callback or the then. The code will not wait for `$.post` to return before moving to that if statement.

```
if (item == null || item == undefined) {
    alert("TTEMST");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition, which has alert won't wait for the Post to complete.

You need that `if` inside the callback of post, like this:

```
$.post('api.php', args, function(response) {

    startSpinner(spinner);
    if (response.status == 0) {
        item = response.data;
        console.log("ITEM: " + JSON.stringify(item));

        if (item == null || item == undefined) {
            alert("TTEMST");
        }
    }
```